# Fluter Deeplinking URL

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, flutter-deep-link

I am following official [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links) for deeplink but I am using without go_router.

I have

```
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
onGenerateRoute: CustomRouter(context).generateRoute,
initialRoute: initialRoute,
);
```

My URL - https://www.com/user/get/info/223de7f0-3600-4421-acd0-ed628694c1e9-85989cd8-8b1c-44e1-b58d-4d48d7fbef46

Now when I click on this URL it opens the app but it shows that no route is defined.

223de7f0-3600-4421-acd0-ed628694c1e9-85989cd8-8b1c-44e1-b58d-4d48d7fbef46 - This id will be different for user wise and I have more than 10000 users.

```
static const String deepLinkUser = '/user/get/info';
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
final args = settings.arguments;
switch (settings.name) {
case RouteName.deepLinkUser:
return doRoute(() => UserScreen(), auth: false);
```

How to resolve this issue? Also it opens second instance of the app.

I tried the implementation as per the doc and my expectation it open the screen based on the defined path.

Comment: It is not opening if the app is killed.